# How to add ZfcUser login form to the ZfcUser route if not authorised and show admin panel if authorised?

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser

Firstly, I have ZfcUser, ZfcAdmin (also I have BjyAuthorize) installed.

I want to show log in form if client is not authenticated and show admin panel if client is authenticated.

**I have to do something with default ZfcUser route `/user`.**

As I realized that module must have route to work properly (is it true?). I tried to rewrite main route of `ZfcUser` to the `/admin/login`. It is worked, but it is not correct. Routes become `/admin/login/login` or `/admin/login/logout`. That is monstrous and not correct, I think.

I don't want to allow this route to client.

**Also, I have detecet user authentication and authorisation and if it is authorised and  authenticated I want to show admin panel, or if it is not, I want to show login form**

I understand, that I can achieve this by adding redirect to each controller, but it is not nice approach, I think.

Is it somehow possible to do that:

1. Detect if user is authorised on controllers level (not in action level)?

1.a. if user is authenticated and authorised to use admin panel controller AdminController will be loaded (it is controller of `ZfcAdmin` module) 

1.b. if user is not authenticated just show log in form (redirect to controller UserController (`ZfcUser` controller or just show view with login form (`ZfcUser` provides this form).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done it, take the zfcuser.global.php.dist file (you can find it inside the config dir of the ZfcUser module), rename it without .dist suffix and place it inside the autoload dir of you application.

ZfcUser is a configurable module and one of its configuration is about where to redirect the user when a correct login happen or if user is already logged in, find this part

```
/**
 * Login Redirect Route
 *
 * Upon successful login the user will be redirected to the entered route
 *
 * Default value: 'zfcuser'
 * Accepted values: A valid route name within your application or a callback.
 *                  If callback used, it will receive the identity as the param
 *
 */
//'login_redirect_route' => 'zfcuser',
```

As you can see it is disabled, so you need to enable it an give a route name (your admin panel route for example).

If you see the UserController there is a check at the beginning of those actions that need authentication

```
if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute());
}
```

If you have modules that are accessible to authenticated users only one solution should be to create a small module that do this checking in the onBootstrap event. You will have a configuration file where you'll list these modules and the code will be something similar to the [EdpModuleLayout](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts/blob/master/Module.php).

But please note that actually I've never used BjyAuthorize and perhaps there is already a solution in it for this issue (can user Guest see Admin module? No? Redirect, no needs to check for auth).

Cheers

Comment: I know about possibility to edit config to edit redirect route after log in or log out. Also, I know that I can add this check it each action, but is there any way to do it for whole controller? Maybe to do it in constructor or on module bootstrap? Also, what to do with default zfcuser route /user? I don't want to show this route for user. I want something like /admin/login and /admin/logout and main admin panel be available on /admin route. How can I do this?